# For loop only runs through one time before finishing program

Tags: java, for-loop

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PassGen {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] characters = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
    StringBuilder b = null;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter password length.");
    int length = scan.nextInt();
    while (length > 20 || length < 6) {
        System.out.println("Password must be between 6 and 20 characters long.");
        length = scan.nextInt();
    }

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        int x = rand.nextInt(characters.length) + 1;
        b = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
        String s = characters[x];
        b.append(s);
    }

    System.out.println("Your password is: " + b.toString());
}
}
```

For some reason when I run this program it only runs through the for loop once before displaying a single random character regardless of the length entered.

Answer (score 2):

No, the loop is running multiple iterations - but on *every* iteration, you're creating a new StringBuilder:

```
// This is inside the loop, but should be outside.
b = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
```

Note that *sometimes*, I'd expect the loop to throw an exception - and if it doesn't, you'll end up with a string which is longer than you want anyway. Basically, you have three off-by-one errors... you should have:

```
b = new StringBuilder(length);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    int x = rand.nextInt(characters.length);
    b.append(characters[x]);
}
```

Also note that it would be simpler if you just had a *string* instead of an array of strings, and used `charAt`:

```
String characters = "ABCDE...9";
...

int x = rand.nextInt(characters.length());
b.append(characters.charAt(x));
```

Comment: darn, I need to type faster :P

Comment: Faster than Jon Skeet?? o.O :P

Answer (score 0):

```
    b = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
```

needs to be outside of the for loop. The way you have it, `b` is created each time the for loop is run.

Answer (score 0):

You always recreate your `b` object inside your loop. It will always contain only one character.